# Robot framework ride installation for Python3.7 CentOS 7.x

Tags: wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

Installation of robot framework ride on centos 7.5 with Python 3.7.4 fails on wxPython installation.

When checking in wxPython repository there is no matching package - https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/centos-7/

Using fedora-31 package completed successfully:
pip install -U  --trusted-host wxpython.org -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/fedora-31 wxPython--proxy

However after installing ride, it fails to find it:
pip install --pre robotframework-ride

## ride.py

wxPython not found.
RIDE depends on wx (wxPython). Historically, the last supported version was 2.8.12.1 with unicode support.At the time of this release the current wxPython version is 4.0.7.post2.You can install with 'pip install wxPython' on most operating systems, or find the the download link from https://wxPython.org/

## pip list

Package             Version

---

certifi             2020.6.20
chardet             3.0.4
coverage            5.2.1
coveralls           2.1.2
docopt              0.6.2
idna                2.10
Jinja2              2.11.2
MarkupSafe          1.1.1
nose                1.3.7
nose-htmloutput     0.6.0
numpy               1.19.1
Pillow              7.2.0
pip                 20.2.3
pygame              1.9.6
Pygments            2.6.1
Pypubsub            4.0.3
requests            2.24.0
robotframework      3.2.2
robotframework-ride 2.0b1
setuptools          50.3.0
six                 1.15.0
urllib3             1.25.10
wheel               0.35.1
wxPython            4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install from Fedora 31 from https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/fedora-31/

For this wxPython 4.1.0 you should install current development version see [RIDE project](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) or current Beta with:

```
pip install --pre robotframework-ride
```